# Getting Rid Of Error Log When Unauthenticated Redirect Fires

Tags: laravel-5.6, laravel-forge

If a user is not registered and tries to reach a page that needs authentication, I redirect the visitor to login with Bolierplate Laravel AuthCode.

However, when I check error log I receive and error. ( It works on client-side without any problems)
***Error Log:***

```
Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException: Unauthenticated. in /home/forge/xyz.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/GuardHelpers.php:40 Stack trace: #0 /home/forge/xyz.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php(292): Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard->authenticate() #1 /home/forge/xyz.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(57): Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager->__call('authenticate', Array) #2 /home/forge/xyz.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(41): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate->authenticate(Array) #3 /home/forge/xyz.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure)) #4 /home/forge/xyz.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #5 /home/forge/xyz.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(67): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request)) #6 /home/forge/xyz.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure)) #7 /home/forge/xyz.com/
```

***Code:***

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/login';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        return redirect()->route('login');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your Exception Handler (**app/Exceptions/Handler.php**), there's a property named `$dontReport` which contains the list of exceptions to not report.

```
/**
 * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dontReport = [
    //
];
```

Simply add the exception class to the array.

```
protected $dontReport = [
    \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::class
];
```